# Probability for 75% to 25% in Omaha8?

Tags: omaha-hi-lo

In Omaha Hi/Lo 8s or better, what is the probability for me to win 25% of the pot and 75% of the pot in this situation?

For example:

I have - **A x x 2**

Opponent has - **A 2 6 7**

Board is: **Q 4 5 3 10** (rainbow)

---

Opponent has `3 4 5 6 7` for high pot and 50% for low pot with `A 2 3 4 5`

---

Situation:

I play in limits $1/$2 in Omaha8, opponent raises up to $6, I call:

Flop: **Q 4 5**

Opponent bet pot. I call

Turn: **3**

Opponent again bet pot, I raise to all-in. He calls.

River: **any blank card**

I'll get only 25% of pot.

My question: How often on will I get only 25% of pot?

Comment: Hello, it is unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify this? Please edit it, and then request it be reopened. thanks.

Comment: He's asking for the chance of winning a quarter of a pot to the chance of winning 3/4 of the pot with those holdings...

There's a lot of missing information here, the suites. The low is easy, you need a 6 for a split, no real chance of winning (that's why he asked for 75%, you can't win 100% here). The high can be easily won if you have 2 suited cards that matched up with the board, OR JK for a higher straight. I am sure that's what he's asking. If you win the high and tie the low, it's 75%; if you tie the low and lost the high, it's 25%.

Comment: @YingLi, yeah man! You are right!

Comment: please reopen this!